# How to compare every element of list with one another?

Tags: ocaml

I have two string lists lst1 and lst2. I want to compare every element from lst1 with every element from lst2 by using List operations such as List.map, List.filter.

In other languages, I would just use nested for loops but what should I do in OCaml?

Comment: OCaml has loops. But the idiomatic equivalent in OCaml to a loop in an imperative language is a higher-order function like fold or map. Which one you want to use depends on what the result is supposed to look like.

Comment: Instead of nested loops, you probably want to do nested maps.

Answer (score 2):

If the Lists are guaranteed to be the same length, OCaml has:

```
List.fold_left2 (fun a e1 e2 -> a and (e1=e2)) true lst1 lst2
```

Or, equivalent to the answer provided by @Roma149:

```
(List.combine lst1 lst2) |> (List.fold_left (fun a (e1,e2) -> a and e1=e2) true)
```

But of course, OCaml defines structural equality for every type, so you should probably just go for:

```
lst1 = lst2
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know OCaml, but it seems that you're looking for the functional way to compare two arrays. In this case, I would use something like the `zip` function that is present in many languages, which creates a new array in which each element is an array containing the elements of the input arrays at that index. In OCaml this seems to be `List.combine`.

So, for example, zipping `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` yields `[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]`.

This allows you to use `map` or `filter` to do a comparison for each pair.

For example, in Ruby I'd do something like this:

```
[1,2,3].zip([4,5,6]).map { |x,y| x > y ? x : y }
```

Sorry it's not a complete answer, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Caution: if you decide on using `zip`, you have to remember to deal with the edge case where the two lists have different lengths!